# EF 6: How to add a record in 1 to 0..1 relation

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have the following scenario: A case has a 1 to 0..1 relationship to an appointment (I always need a case to work on. This case does not need to have an appointment. But every appointment needs to have a case.) This is implemented as follows:

```
public class Case
{
    [Key]
    public long CaseId { get; set; }
    public virtual Appointment Appointment { get; set; }
    // ... and several other properties.
}

public class Appointment
{
    [Key]
    public long AppointmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Case Case { get; set; }
    // ... and several other properties.
}

// in OnModelCreating
modelBuilder.Entity<Appointment>().HasRequired(a => a.Case).WithOptional(c => c.Appointment);
```

So far, so good: If I create an appointment and (since I have to do so) the referenced case, everything works fine.

But if I create my case and some time later I would like to create an associated appointment, I always get the exception: "Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'Appointment_Case_Source' of the relationship 'Appointment_Case' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1"

I try to assign appointment to case and vice versa. What is going wrong here?

This is how I try to do this:

```
private void CreateNewAppointment(Case case)
{
    Appointment a = MyRepository<Appointment>.Create();
    a.Case = case;  // and some other properties...
    MyRepository<Appointment>.Update(a);
}
```

MyRepository is a generic repository class with the following methods:

```
public T Create()
{
    return MyContext.Set<T>().Create(); // with MyContext : DbContext
}

public void Update (T record)
{
    if (MyContext.GetEntityState(record) == EntityState.Detached)
    {
        if (record.Id == 0) { MyContext.Set<T>().Add(record); } // here I get this Multiplicity constraint violation...
        // several other things in else
    }
}
```

Kind regards,
Mate

Comment: can you please show the code, where you want to create an associated appointment?

Comment: do you get `case` from source, which you pass to `CreateNewAppointment` method?

Comment: I get it: 'case' was read some time before from the same (and still-alive) context. If I refresh the case directly from the context before passing it to appointment creation, then it works.

Comment: have you tried adding `public long CaseID { get; set; }` property to `Appointment class?`

Comment: I started to do so, but then I got some trouble because of my 1 to 0..1-relation. If I use the foreign key, EF wants to establish a 1 to many-relation. And an unique index does not work because of the possible null-values. The way it works currently, Case and Appointment in fact do share the same IDs.